# Convert String to int array in Java the fast way

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

does anyone know a *faster* way to convert string to int array?

Java V7

The format given is "`4 343 234 -24`" and so on. Spaces between the numbers, amount of numbers is known beforhand just as is the range within the numbers are

```
long[] array = new long[length];            
for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt(n.substring(0, n.indexOf(' ')));
    n = n.substring(n.substring(0, n.indexOf(' ')).length() + 1);
}
array[length - 1] = Integer.parseInt(n);
```

Comment: If it is working already better you post it on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: try splitting the input string into the component numbers then converting each of those to a long/int as appropriate

Comment: Just use `String#split` that will split your string depending of a delimiter (use " " here), and you get an array of all different numbers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to review working code belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `String.split()` is by far the most efficient when you want to split by a single character (a space, in your case).

If you are aiming for maximal efficiency when splitting by spaces, then this would be a good solution:

```
List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.asList(kraft.split(" ")).forEach(s->res.add(Integer.parseInt(s)));
Integer[] result = res.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

And this works for any number of numbers.

Comment: @MelissaLoos then hold on one moment. (`List` has some method for converting it to an array, I just can't remember it by heart)

Comment: @ItamarG3 You could add the parsed `int`s directly to an array.

Comment: @Nathan i felt this is more elegant. Not sure why

Comment: @MelissaLoos `Integer` is an object class representing an `int`. Same for `Long` and `long`. You can replace `Integer[] result` by `int[]`.

Comment: There is no need for the intermediate `List`.

Comment: @senjin.hajrulahovic you're right, but this way it's clear to the reader what's going on, what the types are and how this works...

Answer (score 1):

if You are using Java8 or higher version then you can get your expected output by writing this single line of code.

```
String str= "4 343 234 -24";

int[] intArr=Stream.of(str.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArr));
```

Comment: Why the `str1.replace("-", "")`? The question does not mention absolute values.

Comment: Check the Updated Code now.
 l already fixed that by removing The replace() method.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting the input with the pattern `\\s+` would handle one or more white-space characters, not only spaces, appearing between the numbers.

```
Stream.of(input.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

The `mapToInt` method returns an `IntStream` which provides the `toArray` method. This method returns an array containing the elements of the `IntStream`.